# How to set State of functional component from unit test case

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am testing react functional component where i need to click a button before button click it is using some state which is false i want to make true so that my test case will pass.please help

Comment: it('should change dropdown value and click button',()=>{

const ch=orgwrapper.dive().find('#identifier');
ch.simulate('change',{
target:{key:'2'}

});
const btn=orgwrapper.dive().find('#btnbutton')
bt.simulate('click');
});

Answer (score 0):

```
const [data, setData] = useState(false)
const [message, setMessage] = useState()
function onButtonHandler(){
setData((val) => !val)
setMessage("set you message here")
}
```

And use the data and message at places where you put your button

Comment: can you help me how to change state from enzyme testcase before clicking button

Answer (score 0):

```
   const changeSize = jest.fn();
   const wrapper = mount(<App onClick={changeSize} />);
   const handleClick = jest.spyOn(React, "useState");
   handleClick.mockImplementation(size => [size, changeSize]);

   wrapper.find("#para1").simulate("click");
   expect(changeSize).toBeCalled();
```

Or you can try

```
it('testing state ', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Component list={[]} />)
  wrapper.instance().setValue(1)
  expect(wrapper.state('value')).toBe(1)
})
```